# How to set a privilege inside a role in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-identity, privileges

I currently have a system where there is a user table, a role table, and a user-roles association table, where one user can be associated to multiple roles (like Admin, BasicUser, etc.). I am able to authorize action methods based on these roles. This is from the Identity framework.

Now I want to add support for privileges so that action methods can be restricted based on those as well, rather than just by roles. For example, in a Controller, I may have an HTTPPost action that only someone with a "Write" privilege should be able to perform successfully.

What changes do I need to make so that I can assign privileges to roles? I.E., I want to select the "Admin" role to have the "Write" and "Read" privileges, while a "BasicUser" role will only be assigned a "Read" privilege. This way, an Admin can access any method that is allowed by the Write privilege, while the BasicUser can not.

If I were to create another table called "Privilege" and an association table between that and roles, and the code to set privileges in a role, how can I use the privilege as a filter? So for example, the below action should only be allowed to be performed by a user in a role that has the "Write" privilege attributed to it.

```
[Write]
public ActionResult Create()
{
   return View();
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way the [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) works, you can create a custom authorization attribute inheriting from it:

```
public class AuthorizePrivilegeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    // Custom property
    public string Privilege { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // Reusing default authentication. 
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {                
            return false;
        }

        return YourCustomCode.HasPrivilege(this.Privilege))      
    }
}
```

Then using it on top of your method:

```
[AuthorizePrivilege(Privilege = "Write")]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the starting point. Using this technique, will the YourCustomCode class contain the code that checks if the association between the role and the privilege? I.E. all the database code?

Comment: Exactly! Don't forget to mark as answer if you are satisfied with the answer.